# Web service to return image from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-services

Firstly let me tell you that I am a DBA who is trying to cross skill into the world of web development and I'm pretty new to all this and learning as I go.

I have a SQL Server database which has a table that stores images of staff members.

I am currently updating some sales reports in SSRS and on each report will be an image of the sales manager.

What I want to do is create a web service which will accept a staff ID integer as a parameter and return a resized version of the image.

So the image url on the report will be something like http://photoserver.com/getphoto?id=123456

So some sort of . Net C# code to do this.

I know there are other ways to achieve this, but I really want to learn how to develop these kind of simple Web services.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently for PowerBI using an Azure Function.  Using IIS on-prem and SSRS would be largely the same code:

```
#r "System.Configuration"
#r "System.Data"

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    // parse query parameter
    string productStr = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "ProductId", true) == 0)
        .Value;

    int productId = int.Parse(productStr);

    string constr = "server=someserver.database.windows.net;database=databasename;user id=imageViererUser;Password=password";

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {

        await con.OpenAsync();
        log.Info("Connection Open.");

        var sql = @"        
        select ThumbnailPhoto
        from SalesLT.Product
        where ProductId = @productId
        ";

        var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@productId", productId));

        var buf = new MemoryStream();

        using (var rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
        {
            if (!rdr.Read())
            {
                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            var stream = rdr.GetStream(0);

            var resp = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            await stream.CopyToAsync(buf);
            buf.Position = 0;

            log.Info($"Image Read {buf.Length} bytes");

            resp.Content = new StreamContent(buf);

            resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/gif");

            return resp;

        }
    }


}
```

Then you’ll get a url for image retrieval like this:

https://yourfunction.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerCSharp1?code=E0Xw32IKcJadkr6OmhzUVoEaLXpQLDgsA0WerH3EcaOL7yKhDKiyg==&ProductId=952

Then you can add a calculated column to the Product table in your PowerBI model like thise:

ProductImageUrl = "https://yourfunction.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerCSharp1?code=E0Xw32IKcJadkr6OmhzUVoEaLXpQLDgsA0WerH3EcaOL7yKhDKiyg==&ProductId=" & 'SalesLT Product'[ProductID]

Comment: Super helpful, I will explore this and come back to you.